# API Explorer: Missing Certificate Error

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I am following these instructions: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

Everything seems to work, but I am getting a "Missing certificate" trying to connect to the API Explorer. My private key uploads just fine.

I am leaving the "End User ID" blank because I am not sure what to put there, and the instructions do not specify what to put there.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting the missing cert.  Could be wrong error message.    For the end user id, this would be how you were going to identify the end user in your system. You need to keep track of what you use, so that it can be deleted later. It can be anything, just keep track of it.

Comment: Could you try clearing your cache and uploading your cert again.

Comment: clearing my cookies is what fixed the problem. Please make it an answer so I can choose it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: (in the comment above)

Could you try clearing your cache and uploading your cert again. –  Jarred Keneally